# For Loops in C++ - Variables not being incremented properly

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010-express

I have been trying to write some code that asks the user for several debit entries for an accounting program. If the user gives 5 as the answer, the program should ask him the debit entry's name and amount 5 times before continuing on to the next line of code. So, I used for loops to solve this problem and it seems something strange is happening. 


This is the format in which the code should run when being compiled and executed:

***How many debit entries do you wish to make?: 2

1. Debit Entry Name: example1

1. Debit Amount: 123

2. Debit Entry Name: example2

2. Debit Amount: 456***

*continue on to next line of code*

Here's the code I've written in C++ for this part of the accounting program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "How many debit entries do you wish to make?: ";
   int entries;
   cin >> entries;
   string debitNames[50];
   float debitAmounts[50];
   int offset = 0;
   int number = 1;
   for (offset = 0; offset < entries; offset++)
   {
      cout << number << ". Debit Entry Name: ";
      cin >> debitNames[offset];
      cout << number << ". Debit Amount: ";
      cin >> debitAmounts[offset];
      for (number = 1; number <= entries; number++)
      {
      }
   }
   char response;
   cin >> response;
   return 0;
}
```

The outcome is extremely strange, here is what happens when I compile and run it:

***How many debit entries to do you wish to make?: 5

1. Debit Entry Name: example1

1. Debit Amount: 123

6. Debit Entry Name: example2

6. Debit Amount : 123

6. Debit Entry Name: example3

6. Debit Amount: 123

6. Debit Entry Name: example4

6. Debit Amount: 123

6. Debit Entry Name: example5

6. Debit Amount: 123***

*continue on to next line of code*
The program, after listing the number as 1, suddenly jumps off to 6 and remains there until all the 5 sets of questions have been asked. As you know by now I'm using the 'number' variable to simply tell the user that 'number' entries have been asked, as specified by the user his/herself. Try running this code in your compiler and see whether the same result appears. By the way, I use Visual C++ 20120 Express Edition, could this have anything do with the problem?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, before the loop, you set the `number` variable to 1.

Inside the loop, you set the `number` variable to `(entries + 1)` using this snippet:

```
for (number = 1; number <= entries; number++)
{
}
```

Why not simply do this?

```
cout << (offset + 1) << ". Debit Entry Name: ";
```

Comment: Thanks 'atornblad', this is much better than the code I've written out. Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: But one more thing, why does the for loop increment the 'number' variable by (entries + 1)? Syntactically the for loop is correct. So why does that happen?

Comment: Yeah, but the for loop sets the `number` variable to `1` for every loop, and then increases the `number` variable five times for every loop. Instead of the **loop within a loop** you should really just have written `number++;` and not an entire inner for loop.

Comment: Thanks for the advice atornblad, I understand now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner for loop will always leave number at entries+1:

```
  for (number = 1; number <= entries; number++)
  {
  }
```

Did you mean to use a different variable here, rather than re-use the existing `number`?

Comment: But why does the compiler increment number by (entries + 1)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Alan Stokes.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the bug is in this part of code :

```
for (number = 1; number <= entries; number++)
      {
      }
```

You are using `number` to display debit entry number

And it is incremented in the above loop to `enteries + 1`

Comment: But the question is why is the for loop incrementing the number variable to (entries + 1)?

Comment: Thanks hotadvice for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You output the `number` variable, which you incremented in your inner `for` loop to `entries`+1...

Comment: I don't understand why the compiler increments the 'number' variable by (entries + 1). Can you explain?

Comment: You use a `for` loop, initializing `number` to be one. Then, you test it with the `number<=entries`, executing the loop body, if the condition is met. After each time, you increment the number by one and then check the condition again. Due to `number<=entries`, the condition will be met for `number==entries`, resulting in another increment of `number`.

Comment: Thanks Abrixas2 for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you?

```
  number++;
  for (int number = 1; number <= entries; number++)
  {
  }
```

Also some more close to real life solution is to not to hold this separately. It is much more logical to create struct or class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <time.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct Debt{

  string name;
  float owe;
};


int main()
{
cout << "How many debit entries do you wish to make?: ";
int entries;
cin >> entries;
list<Debt> debts;



for (int offset = 1; offset <= entries; offset++)
{
  Debt debt;

  cout << offset << ". Debit Entry Name: ";
  cin >> debt.name;

  cout << offset << ". Debit Amount: ";
  cin >> debt.owe;

  debts.push_back(debt);

  for (int number = 1; number <= entries; number++)
  {
  }
}
int i=0;
list<Debt>::iterator it;
for ( it=debts.begin() ; it != debts.end(); it++ )
  cout << "Debt seq " << ++i << " Name " << (*it).name << " debt is " << (*it).owe << endl;


char response;
cin >> response;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm still a beginner, but thanks for this piece of code, it'll become very useful when I _do_ understand it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you want to add 1 to the number at the end of the loop. 
The simplest way to do this is to use:

```
    number++;
```

the for loop

```
  for (number = 1; number <= entries; number++)   
  {   
  }
```

is completely unneccesary, when coding, always start with the simplest solution you can imagine and get more complex as you proceed.

Comment: Thanks for the advice James Allan.